# Calculating cost of an instruction in assembly language

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction

I am reading about code generation from the dragon book. It gives a naive method to associate a cost with each target language association.

> We shall assume each target-language instruction has an associated cost. For simplicity, we take the cost of an in­struction to be one
>   plus the costs associated with the addressing modes of the operands.
>   **This cost corresponds to the length in words of the instruction.**
>   Addressing modes involving registers have zero additional cost, while
>   those in­volving a memory location or constant in them have an
>   additional cost of one, **because such operands have to be stored in the
>   words following the instruction.**

Some examples:

- The instruction **LD R0,R1** copies the contents of register R1 into register R0. This
  instruction has a cost of one because no additional memory words are
  required.
- The instruction **LD R0,M** loads the contents of memory location M into register R0. The cost is two since the address of
  memory location M is in the word following the instruction.
- The
  instruction **LD R1,*100(R2)** loads into register R1 the value given
  by *contents(contents(100+contents(R2)))*. The cost is three
  because the constant 100 is stored in the word following the instruction. Here *contents(x)* denotes the contents of the register or memory location represented by x.

I understood the cost calculation for the first 2 examples. I don't get the third one. How is the cost 3? Also I don't understand the bold part in the quoted text above.

Of what I partially understood I supposed the cost of **BLTZ *R3,R0** to be 3 as it is so for the similar third example above. But the cost of this is 1. How?

*Note BLTZ r, L causes a jump to label L if the value in register r is
less than zero, and allows control to pass to the next machine instruction
if not.*

Comment: In my copy of the book, the cost of `LD R1, *100(R2)` is given as two: "The cost is two because the constant 100 is stored in the word following the instructions".

Comment: @chill I rechecked, it's 3 in my book - 2nd edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't get the third one. How is the cost 3?

- 1 for the instruction
- 1 for fetching the constant 100 from the next word
- 1 for fetching the value from R2+100

> cost of BLTZ *R3,R0 to be 3 as it is so for the similar third example
>   above. But the cost of this is 1. How?

Because: *Addressing modes involving registers have zero additional cost*.

> I don't understand the bold part in the quoted text above.

Apparently the machine code for this architecture uses a word to specify the opcode along with the register operands, and an additional word if needed for a constant.

For example `LD R1,*100(R2)` takes 2 words. The first specifies the operation (`LD` with a register-relative offset) along with the destination register `R1` and the base register `R2`. These are bitfields in the word. The second word then contains the `100` which the cpu knows to fetch because of the opcode in the first word.

Some fixed-length architectures pack constants into the first word, but then obviously they can only have limited range. Using a separate word allows for full range.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure others could explain this better. But however, here are some inspirations:

**The costs are *NOT* real, they are *assumed* by definition of the Dragon book.** To get informed about the *real* costs, you have to check the tables of the target architecture. See the SO wiki for the corresponding links.

So coming to the three examples by relating to your quote above:

> we take the cost of an in­struction to be one

Therefore every instruction is assumed to have *a cost of one*!

> those in­volving a memory location or constant in them have an additional cost of one

So the examples 1 to 3 have

- 1 instruction + 0 mem/const = 1
- 1 instruction + 1 mem = 2
- 1 instruction + 1 mem + 1 one const = 3

The memory addresses and the constants are encoded in the instruction OpCode separately in the additional ***words of the instruction*** prolonging the, to be fetched, OpCode bytes affecting the CPU Op/microOp processing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [list of errors in dragon book](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/dragon/errata1.html). The problem you have stated, is at page 515 in my book and the list says at page 515

> The cost of the instruction is two, not three

Answer (score 0):

It is an error on the book.

The cost model involves only instruction length

> This length corresponds to the length of words of the instruction

Memory operations do not add to the cost, e.g. `LD R1, *R2` has cost 1, because

> addressing modes involving registers has zero additional cost

and there are no constants (either offsets or literal memory addresses) involved.

There is no mention of additional costs because an instruction accesses memory.

Which also explains why the cost of `BLTZ *R3, R0` is one: because the instruction length is one word and the addressing mode (`*R3`) does nor involve constants.

Answer (score 0):

In relative terms, much has changed since the Dragon book. Multiplies have come down from 40 cycles (int) to 1/2 a cycle, and from 200-300 cycles (float) to ... well, I can't remember, but I think less than 10.

The cost of memory access has gone through the roof, though, because processors sped up while memory did not match those increases. A significant amount of optimization work now is cache line oriented (making sure that instructions with locality to each other access data from within a single cache line if possible), and since you can't predict which memory accesses will be cache misses, you can no longer easily predict execution times from within the compiler.

Comment: +1, the cost model suggested in the question is nothing like the cost model on x86 (a popular variable-length instruction set), where short instructions are nice, but things like uop caches often avoid bottlenecks on the front-end.  See also http://agner.org/optimize/, and other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  ARM thumb2 is another very widely used instruction set, but any given instruction has fixed length, and can't be longer to accommodate a longer addressing mode the way x86 can.

Comment: But integer multiply throughput is typical 1 per clock, with 3 cycle latency on Ryzen and Sandybridge.  AFAIK, no x86 CPUs have better than 1 per clock throughput for scalar integer multiply.  (But Skylake has 2-per-clock vector integer multiply for some element widths.)  For FP mul, Haswell and later have 2-per-clock multiply and FMA, with 5 or 4 cycle latency.  (For vectors up to 256-bits: 4 `double`s or 8 `float` per vector, or for scalar).